# can't open my oracle database in a browser

Tags: linux, oracle11g

Excuse me but I am new in oracle 11g. Here is my problem: I finished creating my database with the assistant dbca. In the end it gives me a link with which I can try to open my Database on a browser but when I try anything. I'm lost pardon help me

Comment: Please try to post more detailed questions to get some help. For our point of view, there is a link ( that we don't know) that gives you some problems (but we don't know what the problem is). As is, it's quite impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

When Oracle database is installed, it is accessed by many ways most commonly using sqlplus utility from command prompt. Other way around you are asking it to open in a browser! right it could't be ,oracle provides OEM usually named as dbconsole.
check from command prompt

emctl dbconsole status

emctl dbconsole start

then find the link for dbconsole link which is like as following 
https://localhost:1158/em

openning this will as you credentials , hope so it will work!

Comment: i do it but nothing in a browser. a person told me to put firefox security to "0" but i don't know how can i put it to "0"

Comment: has db console installed with database?